# How does Hibernate keep track of object internally if no identifier is defined in the entity?

Tags: hibernate

As per Hibernate reference doc

> The identifier property is strictly optional. You can leave them off
>   and let Hibernate keep track of object identifiers internally.

How does Hibernate keep track of object internally if no identifier is defined in the entity?

Extending the question further, if there is no identifier how do we load()/get() the entity to make it persistence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means you don't have to manage the identifiers yourself and don't need the property in your Entity, but you need at least a backing field to store it and let Hibernate manage it, except for Components which are parts of an Entity and dont have an identity on their own.

Comment: How do I tell the Hibernate which is the backing field?

Comment: you specify that in the mapping

Comment: Can you give some example of the same??

Comment: `<id name="myId" access="backing_field" ...`

Comment: so we end up declaring the id, so how is it optional? what I understand from optional is I can ignore declaring it altogether... correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: i must admit i'm not sure what exactly is meant here. There are several ways to **not** declare an extra id property: make other/all properties the id, implement a virtual id property by implementing `PropertyAccessor`, declare the class as embedded/component. I never saw a builtin function which does one of the above automaticly

Answer (score 0):

Your quote is from version 3.5 documentation of Hibernate.

As of later versions Hibernate is a JPA provider. In JPA an id declaration is not optional. So in 3.6 documentation you will find this [this note](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#persistent-classes-pojo-identifier):

> Historically this was considered option. While still not (yet) enforced, this should be considered a deprecated feature as it will be completely required to provide a identifier property in an upcoming release.

Hibernate used the Java or object identity to distinguish objects in the session. You load / save as usually but you can't distinguish different rows with the same values. And of course you can't load by key, only by a query. Some of the restrictions evolving from this are mentioned in the [3.5 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#persistent-classes-pojo-identifier).

Comment: I'm quoting from "Hibernate Reference Documentation 3.5.6-Final" sub heading "4.1.2. Provide an identifier property (optional)" on page 52 (in case you are using the pdf version)

Comment: Manage what exactly? The objects in the session are distinct because of their Java object identity. There is no additional identifier in the sense of a primary key, that is why you can't merge a detached object into the session. You get the same restrictions that you get when you create a database table without primary key. You can access the data, but you can't distinguish rows with the same content. This mode of operation is not very useful in most cases. But as it is stated at another place and topic in the doc: "It is not recommended, but it is possible. In the end it is your application."