# How can we tell Hibernate to make identifier properties as optional

Tags: java, hibernate

The [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch26.html), says that:

> Hibernate makes identifier properties optional. There are a range of
>   reasons why you should use them. We recommend that identifiers be
>   'synthetic', that is, generated with no business meaning.

As it says the identifier is optional I tried to create an entity without `@Id` annotation to any of the fields. Then I got an exception as:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
No identifier specified for entity: org.hibernate.tutorials.User
```

Then what it means that `Hibernate makes identifier properties optional.` Can someone please explain?

Comment: **[3.4. Optional configuration properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional)**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314453/how-does-hibernate-keep-track-of-object-internally-if-no-identifier-is-defined-i

Comment: @DozortsevAnton, I don't see any details for identifier property in the link you have shared, so it means `@Id` is not optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optionality of the identifiers relates to the fact that you don't have to create the **content** of the column yourself because Hibernate can automatically generate it.

Contrary, it would not be very smart to have no identifying column in a table, hence Hibernate requires you to define a corresponding field in your Entity classes to hold some kind of identifying value. That doesn't necessarily have to be the auto increment thing, but of course, every Entity needs the `@Id` Annotation on one of its fields, preferably a `String` or `int`